# Transform function view in Class Based View in Django

Tags: python, django, class

I have an archive page with a form that has 2 select option inputs with year and months and I want to select from the database the objects that were created at the year and month selected from the page, I have this function view that works fine but I need the CBV version, I tried with View but it's not working, please a little of help.

```
def archive(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        year = datetime.strptime(request.POST.get('year'), '%Y')
        month = datetime.strptime(request.POST.get('month'), '%m')
        incomes = Income.objects.filter(
            user=request.user, created_date__year=year.year, created_date__month=month.month)
        spendings = Spending.objects.filter(
            user=request.user, created_date__year=year.year, created_date__month=month.month)
    else:
        incomes = Income.objects.filter(user=request.user)
        spendings = Spending.objects.filter(user=request.user)
        year, month = False, False

    context = {
        'title': 'Archive',
        'spendings': spendings,
        'incomes': incomes,
        'currency': Profile.objects.get(user=request.user).currency,
        'total_incomes': round(assembly(incomes), 2),
        'total_spendings': round(assembly(spendings), 2),
        'total_savings': round(assembly(incomes) - assembly(spendings), 2),
        'year': year,
        'month': month,
    }
    return render(request, 'users/archive.html', context)
```

Comment: Can you elaborate more on what you need this CBV to look like and do?

Comment: I need to have a CVB that renders where for the first acces of the page will be listed all the objects that are for the users that is logged in and for this case the objects are obtained in the else statement and on the page is a form with 2 inputs thate are of type select. The user will chose a year and a month and after they hit submit the if satement will get the year and the month from the request and it will filter the objects by these arguments and give them just these objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try writing a class as follows:-

```
class MyView(View):
    template_name = 'mytemplate.html'
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        context = self.get_context_data(**kwargs)
        # change context in case of get method / other code
        return render(request, self.template_name, context)
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        context = self.get_context_data(**kwargs)
        # change context in case of post method / other code
        return render(request, self.template_name, context)
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = {}
        # common code to run in case of any method
        return context
```